# concatenate content files in loop

Tags: javascript

I want to loop over a list of entitlements and create a concatenated json array.
I want to loop over several data arrays and concatenate the ones that the user is entitled to.

```
const ROOSEVELT = require("./content/roosevelt") // these are .js arrays
const AMBITION = require("./content/ambition")
const CHAUCER = require ("./content/chaucer")

// beginning main function
exports.function = function (searchTerm, searchAuthor, searchQOTD) {

var entitlements = GET_REMOTE.checkEntitlements()

// returns json ["ROOSEVELT", "AMBITION", "CHAUCER"] from API server

var entitled_content = [] //empty target array

entitlements.forEach(function(item, array)

// loop over the list of entitlements

{ //this is where I want to concatenate the constants 
// ROOSEVELT, AMBITION, and CHAUCER
// I need a one liner that adds each constant to the entitled_content array.

;});

// main function continues
```

Comment: please identify what you want entitled_content looks like in JS syntax, the word json array confused me a bit

Comment: [{tags: ["roosevelt"], text: "Happiness is not a goal; it is a by-product. --Eleanor Roosevelt", image: {url: "images/"}}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow your imports to be looked up by way of a string since that is what `checkEntitlements()` is returning.

An easy way to is add this imports to a `lookup` object:

```
const ROOSEVELT = require("./content/roosevelt") // these are .js arrays
const AMBITION = require("./content/ambition")
const CHAUCER = require ("./content/chaucer")

const lookup = {
    ROOSEVELT: ROOSEVELT,
    AMBITION: AMBITION,
    CHAUCER: CHAUCER
};
```

> The downside with this is, you have the manually maintain your `lookup` object. If you want this to be automatically generated based on the files you are importing, you can look to use an NPM module such as [require-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir), that'll return this object for you to use directly.
>
> ```
> const requireDir = require('require-dir');
> const lookup = requireDir('./content');
> ```

Next, when you loop through your array of strings, I *think* you want your `entitled_content` to be a flat list. If so, the [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function is what you want.

Otherwise, [`entitled_content.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) would simply append your data to your array.

```
const ROOSEVELT = require('./content/roosevelt'); // these are .js arrays
const AMBITION = require('./content/ambition');
const CHAUCER = require('./content/chaucer');

const lookup = {
    ROOSEVELT,
    AMBITION,
    CHAUCER,
};

exports.function = function(searchTerm, searchAuthor, searchQOTD) {
    // returns json ["ROOSEVELT", "AMBITION", "CHAUCER"] from API server
    var entitlements = GET_REMOTE.checkEntitlements();

    var entitled_content = [];

    entitlements.forEach(function(item) {
        if (lookup[item]) {
            entitled_content = entitled_content.concat(lookup[item]);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This produces an error at the second ROOSEVELT "SyntaxError: invalid object initializer".  Google seems to suggest that the lookup object should be a key-value pair?

Comment: I was using the ES6 [Property Shorthand](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand) notation, which allows you to forgo the colon / value. If your node environment doesn't support that, you can use the old syntax. I've edited the post above to use the older syntax. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015 for more examples.